# Not able to Pass value to Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page in which there are 2 Date field. But when I click on Show button those are not passing the value in show method.

```
<apex:page controller="SelectTimePeriod_VFController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Select Start and End Date">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputField value="{!projectDetails.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!projectDetails.Project_End_Date__c}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!showData}" value="Show" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Project and Resource Details">
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

```
public with sharing class SelectTimePeriod_VFController {

    public static Project__c projectDetails {get; set;}
    public static Boolean isDateSelected {get; set;} 
    public static String Check{get; set;}  

    public SelectTimePeriod_VFController() {
        projectDetails = new Project__c();
        isDateSelected=false;
    }

    public PageReference ShowData(){
        System.debug('$$$$Test: '+ Check);
        System.debug('$$$$Test: '+ projectDetails.Name);
        System.debug('$$$$Test: '+ projectDetails.Project_End_Date__c);
        isDateSelected=true;

        return null;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!showData}' in component  in page selecttimeperiod_vfpage: Class.SelectTimePeriod_VFController.ShowData: line 14,column 1
>   Class.SelectTimePeriod_VFController.ShowData: line 14,column 1

Answer (score 2):

To fix, remove the static from the properties e.g.:

```
public static Project__c projectDetails {get; set;}
```

becomes:

```
public Project__c projectDetails {get; set;}
```

as `static` fields are not included in the view state mechanism of Visualforce that ensures controller values are populated when a request is made back to the server.

See e.g. [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As Keith stated you will have to remove static and change to sObject.Please find the examples below to get values from vf to controller:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
<apex:inputfield value="{!co.CustomField__c}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with MyController {
/*Controller code sets this custom object reference
When the page is first displayed the CustomField__c value comes from here
When the form is submitted, the CustomField__c value is automatically 
updated*/

public CustomObject__c co {get; set;}

// An action initiated from the Visualforce
public PageReference save() {

system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@' +co.Custom_field__c);
}
}
```

Example 2:

```
<apex:page controller="aaPage52">
    <apex:form id="RID">
        <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!TestX}" rerender="RID">
            <apex:param name="X" value="{!X + 1}" />
        </apex:commandButton>
        <apex:outputText value="{!X}"/><br/>

        <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!TestX2}" rerender="RID">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!X2}" value="{!X2 + 1}" />
        </apex:commandButton>
        <apex:outputText value="{!X2}"/><br/>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class aaPage52 {
    public Integer X { get; set; }
    public Integer X2 { get; set; }

    public aaPage52() {
        X = 0;
        X2 = 0;
    }
    public PageReference TestX() {
        String strX = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('X');
        if (strX != null) {
            this.X = Integer.ValueOf(strX);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference TestX2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```